# D3DCompileFromFile with D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I had an old code using directX 9 and 10 and built on it using DirectX 11 and Effects 11 (with D3DX11). Everything was working.
I decided to get rid of any deprecated code, and use only the D3D libraries. However, I still want to use the Effects framework.

I converted the code to use DirectXMath (D3DXVECTOR4 to XMFLOAT4 etc). I changed de D3DX functions, etc.
My code compiles, but at runtime D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory returns an error. I wonder if the binary code returned by DXUTCompileFromFile is not read correctly by the function ? Should I still use D3DX11CompileFromFile (which I think is deprecated) ? But then I will have to include d3dx11.h.

Thank you for your help.

```
ID3DBlob* compileShader = 0;
ID3DBlob* compilationMsgs = 0;

V_RETURN( DXUTCompileFromFile(L"EffectsFile.fx", pShaderMacros, NULL, "fx_5_0", dwShaderFlags, 0, &compileShader) );

V_RETURN( D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory( compileShader->GetBufferPointer(),
    compileShader->GetBufferSize(), 0, pd3dDevice, &g_pEffect) );

compileShader->Release();
```

Comment: What is the returned error?  Are you certain that `compileShader` is non-NULL?  You can also try compiling the effect offline using `fxc.exe` and loading it directly (versus compiling at run-time) and see if that works.  Either way keep in mind that the Effects framework is also deprecated, not just D3DX.

Comment: @MooseBoys Thank you, I found my problem as you can see, it was coming from the Effects library itself. Concerning the Effects framework, I understand it's deprecated but at the same time there are so many techniques used in this program that I feel overwhelmed by the idea to break down everything into shaders... (+ it's quite convenient to access to the shader variables with the effects methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was from my Effects11.lib.
I guess it was compiled using the June 2010 toolkits.

When following the directions here https://fx11.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Effects%2011 everything works.